# Execute an Excel formula into another sheet

Tags: excel, formula

I have a very big Excel formula made for a sheet A for example.

If I only change the reference to cells according to the name of the sheet, and I execute it into a sheet B, I have different results (I guess it's because of offsets in some functions, who aren't related to the sheet A).

So is there a possibility where I can execute a function from another sheet ?
Something like "EXEC(my_function, "Sheet 1")"

EDIT : My function retrieve for example the line number of the first cell empty from differents parameters.

It works pretty good on Sheet1, but if I put it into another sheet, it outputs 0

In french :

```
=(MIN(SI(ESTVIDE(INDIRECT(ADRESSE(LIGNE(INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A65535;EQUIV("NRUTI_03";Sheet1!A1:A65535;0);1));4)):Sheet1!D65535);LIGNE((INDIRECT(ADRESSE(LIGNE(INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A65535;EQUIV("NRUTI_03";Sheet1!A1:A65535;0);1));4)):Sheet1!D65535)))))
```

In english, it should correspond to :

```
    =(MIN(IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(LINE(INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A65535;MATCH("NRUTI_03";Sheet1!A1:A65535;0);1));4)):Sheet1!D65535);LINE((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(LINE(INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A65535;MATCH("NRUTI_03";Sheet1!A1:A65535;0);1));4)):Sheet1!D65535)))))
```

Example :
If I want to make a basic sum in the sheet A, I'll do =SUM(A1:A5).
I want it to be executed on the sheet A, and retrieve the result on sheet B, without putting this formula into the sheet A.
Something like "EXEC(my_function, "Sheet 1")"

Comment: Struggling to understand exactly what you meant. Would creating a UDF be helpfull in your case? Maybe you can elaborate a bit more through sample data, expected output etc.

Comment: Why not just enter a formula in Sheet 1, and then refer to it with `='Sheet 1'!A1`?

Comment: @jsheeran I can't because my formula is something dynamic who count elements from another sheet. Even if I hide this formula, the end user will have to put a formula into the sheet...

Comment: @JvdV I added a simple example

Comment: This confuses even more. You have to type a formula in a cell, this cell is either on sheet A or B, without a sheet reference in your formula it would always apply to the sheet you type it on. If you want to execute a formula on sheet A but with data from sheet B, just add a sheet reference.

Comment: Okay I just changed the example to make it simpler.

Comment: Instead of using `INDIRECT`, can you show an example through actual data. Show us a sample of the data, your searchcriteria and expected results. Hopefully it will get clearer that way.